# What is the meaning of "ratio" in the second Catilinarian V.9?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, cicero

Having finally gotten a basic handle on the sorts of things *rés* can mean, I find myself stymied by *ratió*. I've understood it as meaning essentially "process of (logical) thinking," and that tends to work, though what it means more specifically in any given circumstance still evades me far more often than I'd like.

But then I see Cicero's *In Catilinam* II.V.9, which begins

> Atque, ut ejus díversa studia in dissimilí ratióne perspicere possitis. . . .

which I would translate, if I were sacrificing style to exactitude of meaning,

> But, that you might be able to see clearly his various enthusiasms by a different thought process. . . .

Cicero then goes on to offer two metaphors: that of a gladiator inclined to crime and that of a worthless, good-for-nothing actor.

My inclination here would be to think that *ratio* referred to the method Cicero was using to describe Catiline's associates—a Latin version of "let me say it in another way."

The translations that I've seen, however, seem to take a different approach. Michael Grant's (which to be sure often goes for elegance and style over meaning) is

> And note well the diversity of his interests, the wide range of his activities.

Gould and Whiteley, in their student commentary, offer for *dissimilí ratióne*

> in a very different sphere.

Yonge translates the clause

> And, that you may understand the diversity of his pursuits and the variety of his designs. . . .

In all of these, the translators seem to be taking *ratió* as referring to Catiline's actions or habits. And I'm having a lot of trouble understanding *ratió* as "activities," "sphere," or even "designs." This last comes closest to my understanding of *ratió*, but it's still pretty far from it.

Can somebody help me out? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context I see *studium* as endeavor, activity or interest.
I understand *in dissimili ratione perspicere* as "to see in a different way".
Therefore I offer these translations:

> *Atque ut eius diversa studia in dissimili ratione perspicere possitis…*
>   And so that you could examine his diverse interests in a different way…
>   And to offer you a way to see his various endeavors from another angle…

Notice that I took *in dissimili ratione* to modify *perspicere*.
If you read that as modifying *diversa studia*, the picture changes, but that sounds less natural to me — although the translators you cite seem to have chosen this reading.

(Read the whole sentence in context [here](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/cat2.shtml#9).)

Comment: Thank you! If I understand you correctly, you're siding more with me than with the translations—the difference between the two positions being that you and I take the subject of the implied *ratiócinárí* to be Cicero's audience, and the translations I quote take it to be Catiline. This would certainly do less violence to my understanding of the basic meaning of *ratió*.

Comment: @JoelDerfner, that is indeed the case. I can't wrap my head around the *ratio* belonging to Catilina instead of Cicero's audience. If *ratio* referred to Catilina's *studia*, I would expect it to be in plural. The translations seem ir**ratio**nal to me if you permit the pun.

Comment: I permit it, though reluctantly.

Comment: Scholastic Latin uses *ratio* in many ways: for instance, *omnia appetimus sub ratione boni* means something like "we desire all things insofar as we see them as good."

Comment: @brianpck, interesting. I would probably have misinterpreted that. Do you know if such use of *ratio* originates in antiquity? That sounds a bit wrong to my classically trained ear.